# Items getting added to "overflow menu" instead of the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I've been trying to implement a small application from a book which includes adding items to the action bar. The problem occurring is that the items are getting added into the list of the overflow menu (Top right icon with three dots) and not on the main action bar (where it is supposed to).

This is the menu_main file-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context = ".MainActivity"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
    android:title="@string/action_create_order"
    android:icon = "@drawable/create_order"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

This is the MainActivity code-

```
package com.newboston.bitsandpizzas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_create_order:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the application]
I tried setting the showAsAction of both to "always" but the problem still persists.

(The emulator is bluestacks)

Comment: Do you have room in your action bar for the menu item?  If you don't have room, even putting "always" won't fix it.

Comment: @user3331142 Yes there is...the ActionBar only has the app name with the app icon. I uploaded the screenshot so you can have a look.

Comment: This is odd.  I took your code and used it in a working app I'm using and the icon displayed.

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with the emulator?
I'm using bluestacks.

Comment: I would test that by using another emulator.  Genymotion provides free emulation for personal use.  Or, the Android Studio emulators are actually pretty decent now.  Of course, if you can get your hands on an actual Android device that'd be the most helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your screen size and your action bar title, there might not be enough room for you to display even two menu option items. Even if you set it to 'ifRoom' for both which is recommended over 'always', if there's no room the menu items will get displayed in the overflow menu item.

You can verify this by either checking how your layout look in a bigger screen size with more available room for menu items, shorten your action bar title to make more room, or observing the menu item layout in horizontal orientation to see if the problem still persists.

If this is not the problem, please post a screenshot of how your action bar appears when you set both items to "ifRoom" as well as post your code on how you create and inflate the option menu.

Keep in mind that the menu items layout will look different based on the device. Because devices with bigger screen size can show more menu items in the main action bar. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I posted the screenshot and the inflation code. You can check it.

Comment: Have you tested it on your phone or on the Android Studio emulator? And since your class extends Activity, try using android:showAsAction instead of  app:showAsAction.

Comment: Oh! That worked it out! I did some more reading and learned that while using Activity it is supposed to be app: and not android: but the application is still giving this error (even though it is running perfectly)-
"Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" less... (Ctrl+F1) 
When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the showAsAction in the app: namespace, not the android: namespace.  Similarly, when not using the appcompat library, you should be using the android:showAsAction attribute."

Comment: Glad it worked! Will be great if you can accept the answer if it helped you out.

Comment: Oh yes my bad. I'm new :)